# Separating character string in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to split a string of characters from one cell into separate characters in seperate cells?

For example, the text is `154322JW01`. I want to split this into 10 cells with one character each, starting from the first character:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1| 1  5  4  3  2  2  J  W  0  1
```

Comment: If your data is in Column A and you want to retain the first character in Column A itself, then you can use Text To Column option from the menu and manually add Delimiter after each character. This can be applied to entire column or the range of cells in a column.

Answer (score 1):

Say the string is in K1.  In cells A1:J1, use this formula:

```
=MID($K$1,COLUMN(),1)
```

This uses the output cell's column number to display that character position in the string.